# mySQL: Trouble with select query containing | symbol (LIKE and/or REGEXP)

Tags: mysql, regex, select, sql-like

My current query looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE (data LIKE '$findme') OR (data LIKE '%$findme|%') OR (data LIKE '%|$findme%')";
```

The data in this column contains items that are delimited by pipe symbols ("|") and I need the query to find all records that contain any occurrences of an item in this field.  Additionally, if there's only one item in this column, there will not be a "|" symbol present.

EXAMPLE:

```
$findme = "12";
```

QUERY SHOULD MATCH:

```
13|23|12
12
12|23
3|12|42
```

QUERY SHOULD NOT MATCH:

```
123|32
34|123
```

I'm not sure if using REGEXP would make this easier, but if so, any solution is welcome.  Thanks!

SQLFiddle Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32afd/5

Comment: maybe

`$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (data='$findme') OR (data LIKE '$findme|%') OR (data LIKE '%|$findme') OR (data LIKE '%|$findme|%')"`

Comment: I tried that, but "3|12|42" still isn't matched.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32afd/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), you can replace the `|` with commas, and locate your value `$findme` in the pipe-delimited set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
/* Replace | with , and search in the set */
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$find_me', REPLACE(data, '|', ',')) > 0
```

Note that this only works if the delimited values in `data` do not contain commas.

In the long run, the appropriate solution to this is to separate out the delimited column `data` into another properly normalized one to many table.

Comment: They wouldn't contain commas, but this doesn't work.  I get an error that 'FIND_IN_SET' is not a recognized built-in function name.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32afd/8

Comment: @compcentral You have the fiddle set on MS SQL Server 2008.  FIND_IN_SET() is a MySQL function.

Comment: Oops.. my mistake.  Thanks, that seems to work, but what about the "3|12|42" condition.  I tried adding it in fiddle and I got a schema error.

Comment: @compcentral ?? If you got a schema error in SQL Fiddle, you might have forgotten a ; or something.  Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/657c5/1